# File not found error in Ubuntu despite listing absolute path

Tags: python, ubuntu, io

I have this code snippet:

```
import xlrd
import os

path = os.getcwd()
loc = (path+"/file.xlsx")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
```

While this works fine on my Mac, it does not work when I try to run it on Ubuntu, and I'm not sure why. I've verified that the path is correct using `pwd` and `ls` in the terminal. The python file is in the same folder as the spreadsheet I'm trying to open. I've also tried some solutions in Python, that have not worked either:

```
path = os.getcwd()
loc = os.path.join(path, "file.xlsx")
```

Here is the exact error I am getting:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/rips/Desktop/script/file.xlsx'
```

Comment: So, you mean that when you copied the path which is showed in error(/home/rips/Desktop/script/file.xlsx) is correct when you did ls> ?

Comment: @Code_10 yes, the file I want shows up if I do `ls /home/rips/Desktop/script/` in the terminal.

Comment: Can you hardcode the path of file.xlsx in "loc" and check whether that too returns the error?

Comment: @Code_10 just tried that, still throws the error

Answer (score 1):

My code wasn't working because it turns out the excel file had been corrupted. I didn't initially suspect this as I downloaded it as an email attachment from myself on another machine.

For some reason, using this code brought up a different error (that was ultimately more useful in diagnosing the problem):

```
loc = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'script', 'file.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

If python script and file are on same folder you shouldn't use any path prefix to open it, since python "modules" (in this case you script) just start looking up on same folder.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried putting no path at all as well. Still claims the file does not exist